# NoSuchMethodError for TextRenderer draw() method

Tags: java, opengl, canvas, textrenderer

I have a simple custom Canvas

```
import com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import java.awt.*;

import static javax.media.opengl.GL.*;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL2.*;

public class MyCanvas extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener {

private GLU glu;

public MyCanvas() {
    this.addGLEventListener(this);
}

TextRenderer renderer;
@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    renderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 36));

    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    glu = new GLU();
    gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    if (height == 0) height = 1;
    float aspect = (float)width / height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    gl.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glEnd();

    renderer.beginRendering(100, 100);
    renderer.setColor(1.0f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    renderer.draw("Text to draw", 0, 0);
    renderer.endRendering();
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }
}
```

And I have a simple JFrame for displaying this canvas.

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class App extends JFrame {

private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int FPS = 60;

public App() {
    GLCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

    final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, FPS, true);

    this.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (animator.isStarted()) animator.stop();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    this.setTitle("JOGL 2.0 Setup (GLCanvas)");
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    animator.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(App::new);
}
}
```

When I run this program a have a following exeption:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0" com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase$UncaughtAnimatorException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.media.opengl.GLException: Caught NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2.glBufferData(IILjava/nio/Buffer;I)V on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:84)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:449)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:176)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.media.opengl.GLException: Caught NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2.glBufferData(IILjava/nio/Buffer;I)V on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:201)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:202)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:221)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:525)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:77)
... 4 more
    Caused by: javax.media.opengl.GLException: Caught NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2.glBufferData(IILjava/nio/Buffer;I)V on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
at javax.media.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:75)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1311)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2.glBufferData(IILjava/nio/Buffer;I)V
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer$Pipelined_QuadRenderer.<init>(TextRenderer.java:1725)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer$Glyph.draw3D(TextRenderer.java:1445)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer.internal_draw3D(TextRenderer.java:805)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer.draw3D(TextRenderer.java:519)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer.draw(TextRenderer.java:494)
at com.pms.efficiency.MyCanvas.display(MyCanvas.java:70)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:672)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1383)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
... 16 more
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Caught NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2.glBufferData(IILjava/nio/Buffer;I)V on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
at javax.media.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:75)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1311)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:223)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:525)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:579)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:358)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4967)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.opengl.GL2.glBufferData(IILjava/nio/Buffer;I)V
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer$Pipelined_QuadRenderer.<init>(TextRenderer.java:1725)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer$Glyph.draw3D(TextRenderer.java:1445)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer.internal_draw3D(TextRenderer.java:805)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer.draw3D(TextRenderer.java:519)
at com.sun.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer.draw(TextRenderer.java:494)
at com.pms.efficiency.MyCanvas.display(MyCanvas.java:70)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:672)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1383)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
... 28 more
```

The problem in TextRenderer (in Canvas display() method).

```
    renderer.beginRendering(100, 100);
    renderer.setColor(1.0f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    renderer.draw("Text to draw", 0, 0);
    renderer.endRendering();
```

Whithout this code all right: I see black triangle on white background. But I need to add some text on GLCanvas.

Comment: You should first of all using an updated jogl, `javax.media.opengl.GL2;` indicates you are using an old version.

Comment: @elect, so what import should be in updated jogl?

Comment: The import is a signal, you should update all the jars included as dependencies